# Command line tool throws error when running as Automator app

Tags: shell, automator

I have a command line tool which I would like to run with an app.

In Terminal, the tool works flawlessly (it sends a Bluetooth signal to a device and prints some of the steps in Terminal). If that's important: the tool relies on swift-argument-parser that is loaded within Xcode.

When I try either of the following options for creating an app in Automator it works when I hit the run arrow within Automator:

a) via AppleScript

```
on run {input, parameters}

do shell script "./Users/Cerd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myTool-dfdgrdkzualylcafzgfduhdjfkrtk/Build/Products/Debug/myTool param1 param2"

return input
```

end run

b) via Run ShellScript:

```
#!/bin/zsh
cd  /Users/Cerd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myTool-dfdgrdkzualylcafzgfduhdjfkrtk/Build/Products/Debug
./myTool param1 param2
```

However, once I try to run the app outside Automator I get one of the following errors:

a) for Apple Script an error message with "The command terminated due to receipt of a signal."

b) for Run SchellSpricpt a error message without content just ""

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: Need more details like Have you executed the command manually in terminal? If yes then what was the output. Does your tool (script) need any additional library or any environment. Kindly elaborate your question in more detail with the process that you have followed.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the information to the question.